# PHP and regex: how to preg_match on multiple line?

Tags: php, regex

My HTML is:

```
line1
line2

line3 59800 line4
line5
line6
```

My goal is to capture: (25 left characters)59800(25 right characters):

I tried with

```
/.{1,25}59800.{1,25}/igm
```

But I only captures:

```
line3 59800 line4
```

How do I capture multiple lines?

Here is the test: http://regexr.com/39498

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `m`, use the `s` (DOTALL) flag in your regex:

```
/.{1,25}59800.{1,25}/s
```

The `s` modifier is used to make DOT match newlines as well where `m` is used to make anchors `^ and $` match in each line of multiline input.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24619126/1078583), which is correct:

- You don't need the `i` flag as there are no letters mentioned in the regex
- The `g` flag doesn't exist in PHP.
- You can also use `(?s)` to activate `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines

In PHP you can do this:

```
$regex = '~(?s).{1,25}59800.{1,25}~';
if (preg_match($regex, $yourstring, $m)) {
    $thematch = $m[0];
}
else { // No match...
}
```